# How can I call same php function with a parameter and without a parameter simultaneously?

Tags: php

My function is like this:

```
<?php
function facebook_friend_list($username){
............................................
............................................
echo "Number of friends:". $N ;
}
?>
```

My problem:
I have to call This function like this :

```
facebook_friend_list($a);
facebook_friend_list();
facebook_friend_list($t);
............................
............................
```

inside a loop. So, sometimes this function is getting parameter and sometimes it is not getting. When it does not get parameter, it shows  "Missing argument 1 for facebook_friend_list(), called in........................................................."

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Assign a default value to your parameter like `function facebook_friend_list($username = '')` or whatever default value you need

Comment: Can your function handle an empty string or `NULL` as parameter? If so, explicitly pass that, or make it the default param value in the function declaration. See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#~Default+argument+values

Comment: Why do you have to call the function without arguments? What is the meaning of "asking for the friend list of <nobody>" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

  function facebook_friend_list($username = null){

    if($username == null){
         // argument is not given stuff 
    }

    if($username != null){
         // argument is gived to access use :-  echo $username;
    }

    ............................................
    ............................................
   echo "Number of friends:". $N ;
 }

?>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish, but you can make parameters optional by specifying defaults:

```
function facebook_friend_list($username = null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
function facebook_friend_list($username){
```

to

```
function facebook_friend_list($username = '') {
```

Then, within the function `facebook_friend_list()`, make sure to add code to handle the situation when the string is empty.

You can also use a value other than a default string, for example if you wanted it to use a certain username by default, you could type this instead:

```
function facebook_friend_list($username = "exampleusername") {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```html
inside the loop
  if($var != null){
  facebook_friend_list($var);
  }else{
  assign 0 ;
  }
```